# more than 8 outputs detected -- how to solve?

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed `Ubuntu 12.04.3` LTS on the notebook Lenovo IdeaPad z510. Setup was successful. But when I tried to load Ubuntu it gets an error: "**more than 8 outputs detected**".

When I googled about this error, it says this error is related to the Intel Graphics driver, but I am not sure how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

That could be because of a [kernel DRM module bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65988) that's been fixed.  I can't tell from that report which kernel the fix was added to -- try the latest one you can -- but based on [the patch](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=81349&action=edit) it doesn't matter anyway; it's just a dud warning.

So if you don't notice anything else wrong, and it doesn't go away with the latest kernel available in 12.04, don't worry about it.  Keep up with upgrades and it will probably be included soon.